# Entity framework: check if there are changes to be saved from a specific Entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want to detect if changes where made to a specific set of entity before saving.

I am currently using this method but it returns true if there are any Entity modified in the context.

```
const EntityState ModifiedID = EntityState.Modified
                             | EntityState.Added
                             | EntityState.Deleted;

var objectStateEntries = Database.LabelTAB
                          .Context.ObjectStateManager
                          .GetObjectStateEntries(ModifiedID);

return objectStateEntries.Any();
```

Is there any way to detect if there are some unsaved entries in the `LabelTAB` entity only, and not in the entire `Context`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var objectStateEntries = Database.LabelTAB
                                 .Context
                                 .ObjectStateManager
                                 .GetObjectStateEntries(ModifiedID)
                                 .Where(e => e.Entity is LabelTAB);

return objectStateEntries.Any();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
var states  = new List<EntityState>() {  EntityState.Modified,
                                         EntityState.Added,
                                         EntityState.Deleted};

var query = from t in Database.LabelTAB
            where states.Contains(t.EntityState);
```

Each entity has an [`EntityState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entitystate.aspx) property.  Instead of querying the ObjectContext you can just use the property on the entity.