# Creating a smart save button

Tags: c#, .net

I'm designing a desktop app using C#.Net and MSSQL. the app contains a form  where the user can change some values in Text boxes and then press the button to save them in database. following code calls a method to update values and insert them to database beside it shows a message box that confirms the new changes. my problem is that, even the user has not change any value and press the save button the message box will appear again . i tried to compare the values of text boxes before and after change but it dose not work. is it any way to overcome this problem ?

```
  private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int price = Convert.ToInt32(txtPrice.Text);

        Classes.Prices prices = new Classes.Prices(comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString(),
            Convert.ToInt32(txtPrice.Text), 
            Convert.ToInt32(txtCarbohydrate.Text), 
            Convert.ToInt32(txtProtein.Text),
            Convert.ToInt32(txtFat.Text),
            Convert.ToInt32(txtHumidity.Text), 
            Convert.ToInt32(txtminerals.Text));
        try { 
            prices.updateMaterialPrice();
            //this.comboBox1.Refresh();
            this.txtPrice.Refresh();
            int price2 = Convert.ToInt32(txtPrice.Text);
           if (price2 != price)
           {
               MessageBox.Show("new price saved!");
           }

        }
            catch(Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
            foreach (Control ctrl in this.panel1.Controls)
            {
                if (ctrl is TextBox)
                {
                    TextBox textbx = ctrl as TextBox;

                    if (textbx.ReadOnly == false)
                    {
                        textbx.ReadOnly = true;
                        textbx.BackColor = Color.LightBlue;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: So...what are the values of price and price2 when you step through the code?

Comment: @MikeH debugger shows both values as the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that price and price2 will **always** have the same value since you are capturing them both at the moment the user presses the "save" button so you'll always get the message box, it goes like this: User changes the price text box then the user presses the "save" button and the "btnSave_Click" method run, so at this point the txtPrice has the value that the user typed.

I would recommend having a separate layer for data access, use something like entity framework and then you could ask the entity if any of its values has changed.
Check these, they might help you:

[Entity framework: check if there are changes to be saved from a specific Entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6019976/entity-framework-check-if-there-are-changes-to-be-saved-from-a-specific-entity)

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/615499/Models-POCO-Entity-Framework-and-Data-Patterns

Comment: tnx nice approach, i am currently using ADO.NET, in case of using entity framework do i need to change my code for database access and stored procedeure ?

Comment: You can call stored procs from Entity framework and most of the times you'll have to change your code when using EF instead of ADO.Net. It is a different way to handle data and this is often a design choice (and since you mentioned that you are designing a desktop application this might be the right time to do the change).

Answer (score 2):

1- create a flag variable to indicate if the user has started to modify the values or not (let's call it: data is changed), with an initial value of `False`

2- attach event handler to the Change() event of all your textboxes, and inside the event handler, set the flag to TRUE to indicate that we are now safe to go to the DB and save the changed values

3- at the beginning of your Save method, check the value of our flag, if it's false, then do nothing, but if the value is TRUE, then go save your stuff

for example: (pseudo-code)

**1**

```
var dataIsChanged = false;
```

**2**

```
public void ChangedHandlerForTexboxes(object sender, EvenetArgs e)    
{
   dataIsChanged = true;    
}
```

**3**

```
    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       if(dataIsChanged == true)
       { 
int price = Convert.ToInt32(txtPrice.Text);

        Classes.Prices prices = new Classes.Prices(comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString(),
            Convert.ToInt32(txtPrice.Text), 
            Convert.ToInt32(txtCarbohydrate.Text), 
            Convert.ToInt32(txtProtein.Text),
            Convert.ToInt32(txtFat.Text),
            Convert.ToInt32(txtHumidity.Text), 
            Convert.ToInt32(txtminerals.Text));
        try { 
            prices.updateMaterialPrice();
            //this.comboBox1.Refresh();
            this.txtPrice.Refresh();
            int price2 = Convert.ToInt32(txtPrice.Text);
           if (price2 != price)
           {
               MessageBox.Show("new price saved!");
           }

        }
            catch(Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
            foreach (Control ctrl in this.panel1.Controls)
            {
                if (ctrl is TextBox)
                {
                    TextBox textbx = ctrl as TextBox;

                    if (textbx.ReadOnly == false)
                    {
                        textbx.ReadOnly = true;
                        textbx.BackColor = Color.LightBlue;
                    }
                }
            }        

       }
    }
```

Comment: i can not find any change() method in visual studio 2013 , how can i attahc that event to change method ?

Comment: 1- Create the `ChangedHandlerForTexboxes` as shown above, then select each textbox from your form, and in the "Events" tab, navigate to the TextChanged event, and from the dropdown menu, select `ChangedHandlerForTexboxes` method.  this should attach this handler to the textchanged event for every textbox selected.

Comment: @Mohmmed ElSayed i did what u said but the problem still persists!i think because i have a call to database via a stored procedure , that fills the textboxes when form loads